# how to enable jmx remot port for python application?

Tags: java, python, linux, ubuntu, jmx

If jmx could not be enabled, is there a similar way that could be done for python application?

I want to enable the port for monitoring the application, is down or up.

Any suggestions or other way workaround is helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What is jmx? Do you mean Java Management Extensions, or something else?

Comment: yes your right? we use jmx for monitoring the application related stats